Is Centre of Mass a Vector Quantity?
The centre of mass (COM) of a system comprising $n$ particles is defined as:-
$\textrm{COM}=\Large\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i\vec{r_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i}$
Given that the distance ($\vec{r}$) we take here is a vector quantity from a specified point; the numerator is a vector, (sum of $m_i\vec{r_i}$) with the denominator being a scalar (sum of $m_i$), is the centre of mass of a body also a vector quantity? If yes, then what is its direction?

Of course, most of the time a sensible choice of coordinates places the center of mass at the origin.

$\vec r_i$ is not a distance. It is a vector giving the position of the $i$-th point-like body with respect to the origin.

Yes it is.
The vector points from the centre of your coordinates (i.e. the point given by the 0-vector) to the centre of mass of your system.

The centre of mass is at a point in space, and you can represent the position of this point by a position vector relative to a given origin of your co-ordinate system. The direction of this vector is simply the direction of the centre of mass as seen from the origin, and its magnitude is the distance of the centre of mass from the origin.

So are you saying the COM is a vector quantity?

@BobD I am saying that the position of the COM can be represented by a vector.

Yes I agree it CAN be. But must it be? See my discussions below with NuclearHogie.

@BobD No, we don't have to represent the position of the COM by a vector. We could just give it a label and call the position of the COM $X$. But in the calculation quoted by the OP the position of the COM is derived as the weighted sum of position vectors, so in that case, yes, it is being represented by a vector.

I guess I view the vector as a useful tool to determine the location of the COM of the object, as opposed to being an intrinsic physical property of the COM of the object.  If I’m asked what is the force being applied at the COM of a cube, I would need to describe both the magnitude and direction of the force, the latter being the same regardless of the coordinate system used. How would I specify the “direction” of the COM? I suppose I could say a vector pointing to the COM from the origin of the coordinate system, but then which system as it will differ for each one?

In summary I would hope you might agree the question is worthy of debate

To help you answer your own question, consider the following:
While the position of the center of mass (COM), a point in space, may be described by a vector for a specified coordinate system, and while vectors may be a useful tool to determine the location of the COM, the use of vectors is not necessarily required to do so.
For example, if you give me a solid cube of uniform density and ask me for the location of the COM, I could simply say it is at the geometric center of the cube. Note I had no need to use a vector to describe the location of, or anything about, the COM. Moreover, mass itself is a scalar quantity, and a point in space is not a vector.
Even if a vector is used to describe the location of the COM, the magnitude of that vector will depend on the coordinate system used. So it is not a unique property associated with the COM. Contrast this with force, where a vector is essential to its description and the magnitude of that vector is independent of the chosen coordinate system. To be sure, an additional vector can be used to identify the point of application of the force, but that vector is not a property of the force.
So I ask you, do you think the COM is a vector quantity?
Hope this helps.

I don't see the relevance of the discussion about the uniqueness of a vector in different coordinate systems. There's no requirement that vectors be invariant in different reference frames - net force vectors certainly change between non-inertial reference frames. I don't see any need for the vector representation of a COM to be a "unique property", just like the vector representation of velocity or net force will be different in different frames. The COM representation will be different in different frames - so what? That doesn't imply that it is or is not a vector.

@NuclearHoagie I’m not talking about vectors in general, just whether  a vector is required to describe the COM. What is your opinion?

The COM is a position, and position is usually described as a vector quantity. I guess it's not absolutely required to describe it that way, but isn't saying "the COM is at the geometric center of the cube" a cop-out? How do we describe where the center is without vectors?

@NuclearHoagie isn’t it more than just a position? It has the property of mass. I can use a vector to describe the location of a temperature. Does that make temperature a vector quantity?

Dimensional analysis of the COM definition yields a result measured in units of distance - the value of the COM formula is just a position that would remain unchanged even if the mass were scaled up or down arbitrarily. Two concentric spheres have the same center of mass even if they're different masses. I'm not arguing that mass itself is a vector, nor that temperature is - I'd say the analogous measure wouldn't be temperature itself, but rather the "center of temperature" defining the "average position" over which the measurement was made, which would indeed be another position vector.

@NuclearHoagie My problem with calling the COM a vector quantity per se is that the COM Is a real property of a physical object. While all points in space can be described by a position vector, does that necessarily make all the quantities at those points are vector quantities? Anyway, I think it is at least a debatable point (no pun intended!), which is one of the reasons I didn’t give a yes or no answer but rather left it up to the OP to decide. Now the OP can also take your points into consideration.

There are many real physical properties that I think we'd agree are definitely vectors, like velocity, acceleration, or momentum - why should be disallowed for the COM? I'm not sure arbitrary quantities described as a position in space are well described as simple vectors - a temperature at a point in space has a direction from the reference point, a magnitude of distance from the reference point, and a second magnitude of temperature value. But that second temperature magnitude is wholly unrelated to the direction, they're not "coupled" like magnitude and direction of position or velocity.

@NuclearHoagie “I think we'd agree are definitely vectors, like velocity, acceleration, or momentum - why should be disallowed for the COM?”. I’m not saying a vector should be disallowed to represent the position of the COM in some coordinate system. To quote a comment in the link below,  ‘Positions are not vectors… A position is a point. To get a vector, the displacement vector, you need to choose another point arbitrarily which you'll call the ‘origin’ and then the displacement vector is the difference between the point  and the origin”

On the other hand, the velocity, acceleration (and force causing it) and momentum vectors do not depend on the coordinate system. See: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/348232/are-vectors-truly-independent-of-coordinate-systems

Yeah,
you are correct.
Centre of mass is a vector as it is  position dependent.
It all depends what and where the origin is to be considered, meanwhile it is relative.
This giving it a direction and hence it is a vector.
